# Проблема с брейкпоинтами в slick-slider

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Проблема с Слике в том, что когда ставишь брейкпоинт ниже чем 800 пикселей, все перестает работать, например не убираются стрелочки, в то время как если ставить 900 и выше, то все работает чудесно

Comment: Есть кнопка "Вставить фрагмент кода", подключите туда слайдер и вставьте свой код, а мы посмотрим